# Transmission of uint8_t with reception not matching values in client server C program

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have very strange problem with my C client server program.

Let's say I have a function called `net_send(uint8_t *buf)`. This function is used at the client side. Similarly I have function at server called `net_recv(void* buf)`, which just receives the data from client. Pretty simple.

Now the problem is that the server is unable to printf it as a char array. Client and server machines and their compilers support 8-bit char.

An example here:

```
char name[1024];
name[0] = 'k';
name[1] = 'a';
name[2] = 'n';
name[3] = 'e';
```

and rest of the array positions are 0s. 
I called net_send like this

```
net_send((uint8_t*)name);
```

At server side, I receive the data like this:

```
uint8_t buf2[1024];
net_recv(buf2);
printf("%s\n", (unsigned char*) buf2); // prints NOTHING
```

Similarly when I check the values of the first few ASCII decimals of the uint8_t received array, I find this

```
buf2[0] ==> 4 // which is end-of-transmission character
buf2[1] ==> 0 // null character
buf2[2] ==> 'k' // actually an ASCII value for 'k'
buf2[3] ==> 'a' // actually an ASCII value for 'k'
buf2[4] ==> 'n' // actually an ASCII value for 'k'
buf2[5] ==> 'e' // actually an ASCII value for 'k'
```

Why is this weird behaviour? Any ideas?
Even after clearing the first two characters I am unable to print the char array. Even when I create the element to element copy in order to convert the `uint8_t` to `char` values, it does not print the char array. Also if I use the memcpy from the string.h header file, I can't get the char array out of it. Since I cannot get the char array or my string, I cannot do further processing in server.

Any ideas? Or points to how exactly I can convert the received uint8_t to char values to be seen as a char array. Or given above what do you think is happening?

Cheers,
K.

Comment: Have you tried starting the printin from `buf2[2]` where the actual content is?

Comment: I mentioned that. Even I created a new buffer and used the for loop to copy the actual content one by one. Still that new buffer doesn't show anything. Weird!

Comment: looks to me that you net_send function is sending a length count before sending the string (as it should), you need to handle that on the receive. Post the source of net_send

Comment: Note that on the client side, you use a signed char, which you convert to uint8_t and convert to unsigned char on the server side. May not solve your problem, but it seems inconsistent.

Comment: Note also that the receiver needs to ensure that there is a null character after the received data if it plans to use the data as a string.

Comment: @pm100 I have checked the code at both ends. Lengths match perfectly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It has a null character at the end. Plus in the new buffer i made sure i don't miss that.

Comment: @Khawar - you miss my point. The buffer you receive has a 16 bit length prepended to it, your receive code doesnt handle this.

Comment: "I have a function called `net_send(uint8_t buf)`." or do you mean "I have a function called `net_send(uint8_t *buf)`."?  (Added `*`)  2) `buf2[5] ==> 'e' // actually an ascii value for 'k'` --> do you mean `buf2[5] ==> 'e' // actually an ascii value for 'e'`?

Comment: @chux thanks - edited but it is apparent from the second code snippet.

Comment: The question does not contain a [complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Where is the code for `net_send()` and `net_recv()`?  Without that, any possible answer would be based on nothing but guesswork.

Comment: @Khawar again , you are missing what I am saying. nt send is clearly sending a length in fromt of the message. net-recv is not taking it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the buffered data as you describe, you should be able to print by doing this:

```
// Ensure that the data are terminated
buf2[6] = 0;

// print from the third byte
printf("%s\n", (char*) buf2 + 2);
```

If that does not work then either there's something you're not telling us (such as that the server's standard output is redirected to someplace other than where you're looking for the printed data), or else what you *have* told us is incorrect.

As for why you're getting the two bytes `0x04` `0x00` before the data, that is surely part of the protocol employed by `net_send()` and `net_recv()`.  Possibly `net_recv()` is faulty in that it allows those leading metadata bytes to be presented as part of the actual data; we can't speak to that because you've not presented the `net_send()` and `net_recv()` functions.